# Drupal 7 - Add a wrapper around related nodes on Taxonomy term page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

On a taxonomy term page, the taxonomy term info is shown first, followed by related nodes.  I want to add a wrapper div around the related nodes (ex. class="related-nodes").

taxonomy-terms.tpl.php controls the display of the taxonomy term's fields, but I'm not sure how the nodes show up.  I was thinking about making a node template for the taxonomy and doing something like render($content['nodes']).  However, I'm not sure what the $content key would be for the related nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to enable the **Taxonomy term** view display (is disabled by default).
In the view config, you can add classes by clicking in *Settings* of Format option.

Hope it helps.

Regards.